# Relaying requests between third party server and Heroku for static IP

Tags: proxy, static-ip, heroku

I have a rails application hosted on Heroku that I need to integrate with 3rd party payments provider.
The payment provider requires that my application will have a static IP for incoming and outgoing HTTPS requests.
I want to deploy a proxy on a Linode VPS so it can relay the information as a proxy.
Relaying the request to the service provider seems easy, I just use their IP.

Can I relay requests coming from the service provider to the heroku application? Can I realy the request using a URL (https://myapp.herokuapp.com) ?

What is the recommended proxy server to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948434/what-is-a-good-strategy-for-accessing-an-api-which-is-limited-to-a-static-ip-add

Comment: Hello you can use this answer to see how to use NGINX as a reverse proxy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27874505/1345865 http://blog.talenox.com/post/107675614745/how-to-setup-static-ip-on-heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Proximo add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/proximo) to get a known outbound IP address.